# How to change the direction of type in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

I'm trying to create a coffee logo, saying "COFFEE HOUSE", but I can't seem to figure out how to change the type direction into somewhat of a "U" shape. Here's a picture for reference: [image]

I want to add the word "HOUSE" right under coffee, so it satisfies the circle shape. Like this: 
[image]

Can someone help me? I know it's a simple task but I'm a complete newbie when it comes to Illustrator. Please and thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is draw a curved line with the pen tool and then select the text tool and hover over the line. You'll see

the cursor change to this:

[image: Hover to type text]

That will let you type on the line like this:

[image: Type on line]

Sometimes the text is one the wrong side. If so hover over the line in the middle until you see the cursor change to this:

[image: hover over line]

And then click and drag it to the other side of the line:

[image: text moves to other side of line]

Then you should have this:

[image: Final text]

To control where the text ends and starts you can hover over the lines on both sides until you see the cursor change and drag those line inwards or outwards. You will also probably want to choose to center the text for the best look.

[image: Final image]

Comment: :) Have you ever heard of screen captures that dont onvolve your camera?

Comment: Yes. I couldn't use screenshots because they don't include the cursor and these images weren't useful without the cursor showing.

Comment: You can get extra screencapture  software that do include the cursor, snagit is one such tool (highly recommended). There are also free ones.

Comment: A free one is available with irfanview